# How get all the rows value in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am writing the following code to get the values from the Data base using Hibernate

```
try {
    System.out.println("In getDetails() try block");
    configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("resources\\hibernate.cfg.xml");

    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from ServiceManagerDetails");

    List l = query.list();
    Iterator i1 = l.iterator();

    ServiceManagerDetails smd = null;
    while (i1.hasNext()) {
        smd = (ServiceManagerDetails)i1.next();
        System.out.println(smd.getServiceMode());
    }                
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error:- "+e);
    //tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

There are two records but I am getting the value of one row twice. But I have get the value of both the rows. Please help me find out what I am missing. Thanks

Comment: what you have there *should* be correct... can you add the contents of the table to your question?

Comment: May be you have not mapped the id/composite key (primary key) properly.Share the mapping xml file and primary key on that table.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that you have a `one-to-many` association mapped that you have specified a `fetch="select"` method. Hibernate with this will retrieve the parent object for each of the associated records.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from ServiceManagerDetails")
    .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity);
```

Should do the trick.